# mathimatic induction with SUM

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I want to do this with mathimatical induction,for every n>=1.

What I did : I know that basic step is  for n=1 so

```
 ( 1+2    )and I have   (  3 )
 (    3   )             (  3 )
```

step 2 : let assume  n=k is true

```
( n+2   )  it becomes        (  k + 2 ) 
(    3   )                   (     3  )
```

step 3: we have to prove that

```
( k+1   )   =      (  k + 2 ) 
(  2    )          (    3   )
```

we know that n=k+1 so

```
( k+1   )   =      (  k +1 + 2 ) 
 (  2    )          (    3   )
```

it gives us

```
( k+1   )   =      (  k + 3 ) 
 (  2    )          (    3   )
```

not sure if I go right or wrong.

Comment: Using $k$ both in the sum and your induction is sure to confuse you.  Change one of those uses to $m$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The induction is straightforward and follows from [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)

**Base case**

The case $n=1$ is trivial (you made the calculation in you question).

**Inductive hypothesis**

Suppose that  the proposition is true for $n$. This means that we assume that the following is true:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {k+1\choose 2 }={n+2 \choose 3}$$

**Inductive step (Prove that the proposition is true for n+1)**

Consider the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {k+1\choose 2 }=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {k+1\choose 2 }+ {n+2 \choose 2}$$

Since by inductive hypothesis the assertion is true for $n$ we apply the hypothesis for calculate the sum.

Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {k+1\choose 2 }= {n+2\choose 3 }+ {n+2 \choose 2}={n+3 \choose 3}$$

And this complete the induction. Therefore the assertion is true for all $n\geq 1$.

**Remark**

Notice that the least step is possibly since we apply  the pascal`s rule to the sum of the two binomial coefficients.